# Autofac - Do I need to manually dispose IContainer in MVC global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I couldn't seem to find an answer to this question in the docs or stackOverflow (though I may have overlooked it). I'm curious if I should be manually disposing the IContainer that is provided by the ContainerBuilder?

Here's a code sample from Remember.Web:

```
//etc..
IContainer container = builder.Build();//returns IDisposable instance
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
//etc..
```

but I am curious if it should look like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    private IContainer container;//not necessary..?

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ///etc..
        this.container = builder.Build();//returns IDisposable instance
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        //etc..
    }
    protected void Application_End()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Please do point me to the correct docs if I'm overlooking something, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with disposables, the pattern is that you should always dispose of the object as soon as you're done with it. So I would say yes, be explicit about it. The documentation and samples should mention this.

If you do not manually dispose the container, it will be freed (along with any contained instances) by the GC some time after the appdomain is unloaded.

**NOTE:** as @Steven mentions, `Dispose` methods will not be called during garbage collection. Thus, any logic you might have in `Dispose` methods will not be executed. So whether disposing the container has any significance or not depends on the instances held by the container. Again, explicitly calling `Dispose` in `Application_End` will make sure no such logic gets lost.

That said, if you have services in your container that requires disposal, you may want to move those registrations to the request scope. This ensures that disposable instances only live as long as a request. The request lifetime scope is disposed by the Autofac integration module, so no action is required on your part to do the cleanup.

Comment: That's not exactly true. If the AppDomain dies, the runtime will run all finalizers of all objects that still need finalization. So this means that any unmanaged resources (file handles, db connections, references to native memory, GDI+ images) are cleaned. But the Garbage Collector will not call any `Dispose` method for you. So if you do anything more in a dispose method that's not in a finalizer (doing some final logging to a database for instance) that code will not run.